# MIA Airport - connecting international flight with domestic flight

Tags: international-travel, connecting-flights, mia

I am flying from Peru to MIA and connecting to SFO. The layover time I have is 2 hours and 35 minutes. Is it enough for me to get through immigration (I am not a US citizen) and get to the departure gate?

note: I'll have carry-on only and I book my flights with one airline. (book together with AA but the inbound flight is with Latam airline)

Comment: Is the airline willing to sell this as one ticket?

Comment: Yeah I bought it together with AA. It was sold as one ticket from SFO to Lima

Answer (score 5):

There are two benefits of having a single ticket.

The airline has already evaluated the connection, with their knowledge of the flights and airport, and decided to book it.

If anything goes wrong, such as an unusually long delay on the first flight, the airline remains responsible for getting you from Lima to SFO, and will  handle re-booking on a later flight etc.

Answer (score 5):

Not to be overly contrarian, but the answer is "probably". That ticket meets minimum connection time (MCT), but at a particularly busy time immigration in MIA can be an absolute mess. I would expect you'll be okay, but don't dawdle and, once through, go straight to your connecting gate. Since you booked it as one ticket the airline (whoever is actually operating the MIA-SFO flight, whether that's AA or someone else) will be responsible for rebooking you if you miss the connection.

Comment: "Probably" is indeed the most accurate answer. In case of short connection times, AA often sends staff to the jet bridge to pick up the various connecting passengers. Happened to me occasionally, and almost always when flying First class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, AA has full confidence you will be able to make that connection.

If you are eligible, use the [Automated Passport Control (APC)](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/apc) kiosks.  OP does not indicate country of Passport.